# VSCode + Prettier + HTML Formatting wrapAttributes = "force aligned" = contents of the tag aren't indented properly

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

I have these settings in VS Code...

```
"[html]": {
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.html-language-features"
},
"html.format.wrapAttributes": "force-aligned",
"editor.formatOnSave": true,
```

I have an HTML file with this formatting...

```
    <script a="a"
            b="b">
              var x = (function() {
                var y = 123;
              }());
            </script>
```

It should be this...

```
    <script a="a"
            b="b">
      var x = (function() {
        var y = 123;
      }());
    </script>
```

The contents within the tag ought to be indented 2 spaces from the beginning of the tag, not 2 spaces from the beginning of the attributes.  I can't figure out what settings/modules I need to get it right.  Your help is greatly appreciated.